# How to assignment object to 2d vector no match for operator=

Tags: c++, vector

I have 2d vector with object

```
std::vector<std::vector<perceptron>> p;
```

Now I would like to assign object `perceptron` like this

```
PrintRectangle::PrintRectangle(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),
    p(5, std::vector<perceptron>(5))
{

    tech = new teacher(clicked);


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            p[i][j] = new perceptron();
            p[i][j].randweight();
        }
    }

    double learnConst = 0.1;
    //tech->learnPerceptrons(p);
}
```

But I get an error

```
E:\Sieci Neuronowe\Perceptron\printrectangle.cpp:16: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<perceptron> >::value_type {aka perceptron}' and 'perceptron*')
             p[i][j] = new perceptron();
                     ^
```

How can I repair this?

EDIT:

I modeled on the code from C # which was

```
Perceptron[] p;

 p = new Perceptron[10];

 for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
 {
      p[i] = new Perceptron();
      p[i].randweight();
 }
```

In C# this code works fine.
How does it fit in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new` operator creates a *pointer* to an instance of `perceptron`, so the compiler error is correct (`perceptron*` != `perceptron`).

Luckily for you, the vector already pre-created all of your `perceptron` instances when you created the vector, so you can simply remove the line in question.

```
PrintRectangle::PrintRectangle(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),
    p(5, std::vector<perceptron>(5))  // <----------- 25 perceptron objects created here!
{

    tech = new teacher(clicked);


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            // p[i][j] = new perceptron(); NO NEED FOR THIS LINE
            p[i][j].randweight();
        }
    }

    double learnConst = 0.1;
}
```

EDIT: For your updated question (i.e. how to make the C++ code match up with the C# code), you could use smart pointers to store your `perceptron` objects:

```
PrintRectangle::PrintRectangle(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),
    p(5, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<perceptron>>(5))
{

    tech = new teacher(clicked);


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            p[i][j].reset(new perceptron)
            p[i][j]->randweight();
        }
    }

    double learnConst = 0.1;
}
```

I have chosen a `unique_ptr` here for holding `perceptron` pointers, however you should determine what your ownership requirements are and select the best pointer type for your needs (e.g. `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, raw pointer, etc).

**HOWEVER**, unless you *really* need to match the code to what C# does, your code will be probably be faster (and easier to use) the way you did it originally by avoiding pointer overheads (e.g. dereferencing).

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer, I have a question. Can you look on my updated question?

Comment: @Lukassz - If you wanted closer matching code between C++ and C#, you would need to store a vector of (smart) pointers to `perceptron` objects. C# does this internally, and doesn't require you to use C++ pointer syntax. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @lukassz C++ != C#. Use C# as a framework/source of ideas but do not try to duplicate how it manages memory. C# is based around an infinite memory simulator, a garbage collector, while C++ is based around strict and personal control of memory and resources. Take Karl's advice and go with option one. Only dynamically allocate when you have to.

Answer (score 0):

`new perceptron()` returns a pointer to a `percepteron`. If you want the `perceptron` objects to be individually heap allocated, then you need to change `p` to be `vector<vector<pecepteron *>>` (or better, an appropriate smart pointer to a `percepteron`). If individual heap allocation is not important, and `percepteron` has a default constructor that does the acceptable initialization, then you don't need this assignment at all - the allocation of the individual `vector<percepteron>` objects will have already run this constructor.